# WSO2 Identity Server crash

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently testing the `WSO2 Identity Server` and I'm running on an issue.

I currently run `two SSO (SAML2)` enabled apps on my local tomcat on localhost and name app1 and app2.

The behavior of the applications is to redirect to login panel when the user is trying to access the applications.

Since it is SSO enabled, it redirects to `WSO2IS` login panel.

If both application are not logged in and redirected to the SSO login page of WSO2IS. The first one to login works great.

However, the second one to login (the other app already logged in but I'm still on the SSO login page of WSO2IS for the second app) crash in WSO2IS.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

**Here is the stack:**

```
url: https://wso2identity:9443/commonauth
```

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:223)
>     org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:186)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>     org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>     org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>     org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)

Note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.

Comment: What version of Identity Server are you using?

Comment: I'm running 4.6.0. I must say of you try to logon with the same user name for both apps the problem occurs. Also the latest application to do a SSO login request will come out as the first application to login when the user login (Even if it is in login panel of the other apps).

Comment: Why do you had to type, username for the second type. Ideally it should bypass the login page when you try to login second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual SSO flow is, you login to one application. Then if you try to login to another application it, login page should be bypassed and you should able to login without providing your credentials again.

I believe your problem is similar to the scenario reported in [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/MDM-159).

But at it seems what you do is,

1. Goto your first app, click on login then it will redirect to WSO2 Identity Server's SSO login page.
2. Instead of you enter your credential and login to the first app, if you go to second app and click on login then the second app also redirect you to login page of WSO2 Identity Server's SSO page. Now you have two tabs in your browser which have same login page.
3. Now you enter credential on one login page, then it login without a issue.
4. Then you enter same credential on the other login page, then it throws the above exception.

I would say its a poor way of doing SSO. And yet, yes it is a bug and it should fixed on a upcoming release.

HTH,

DarRay

Comment: This is the exact scenario. Thanks for letting me know it is a bug.